# Delphi 2007 IDE hints displayed as HTML text

Tags: delphi, delphi-2007, delphi-ide

Since some days, my *Delphi 2007* IDE has stopped formatting hint's text.

When the cursor moves over a class or a function, it displays hints as plain HTML text.

[image]

Syntax highlight is active and as far as I remember, I didn't change any option in the last months.

[image]

The only thing I can suppose is that, maybe, *Windows 10* updates could have caused this problem but I'm not sure about that.

Comment: I just love how often people want to blame Windows 10 and its updates on their problems. I can't imagine how that's related at all.

Comment: Try running your IDE under a fresh environment. [See here](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/IDE_Command_Line_Switches_and_Options), specifically the `r` parameter.

Comment: @JerryDodge: This wouldn't be the first time Windows 10 updates causes problems to my Delphi 2007. Anyhow, mine is just a suppostion because I didn't apply any changes on the IDE

Comment: @JerryDodge: After running bds.exe with the -r switch resolves the problem.
I've tried comparing the `\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Borland\BDS\5.0` with the new  `\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Borland\foo\5.0` but the only differences I found are RegCompany and RegOwner. Do you know what should I check?

Comment: Then it's probably a package or add-on which is loaded in the IDE startup which is causing it to freak out.