# IDE crash at module jscript9.dll showing the welcome page and function's hints

Tags: delphi, ide, delphi-xe7, delphi-ide

I have *Delphi XE7* installed on a *Windows Server 2012 R2* (64 bit).

One week ago, it started crashing on startup, while displaying the welcome page with the following error message:

```
Firma problema:
  Nome evento problema: APPCRASH
  Nome applicazione:    bds.exe
  Versione applicazione:    21.0.17707.5020
  Timestamp applicazione:   545bd62a
  Nome modulo con errori:   jscript9.dll
  Versione modulo con errori:   11.0.9600.19375
  Timestamp modulo con errori:  5cde2a32
  Codice eccezione: c0000005
  Offset eccezione: 0009192c
  Versione SO:  6.3.9600.2.0.0.272.33
  ID impostazioni locali:   1040
  Informazioni aggiuntive 1:    04c1
  Ulteriori informazioni 2: 04c17c6483616026b1d827b0895ca47b
  Ulteriori informazioni 3: 5521
  Ulteriori informazioni 4: 55212a802421f833061c5f852796fd1e
Leggere l'informativa sulla privacy online:
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=280262
Se l'informativa sulla privacy online non è disponibile, leggere quella offline:
  C:\Windows\system32\it-IT\erofflps.txt
```

I didn't understood the real cause of the problem, I've searched for jscript9.dll and found that it could have been something related to the welcome page, so I've disabled the WelcomePage from the registry and temporarly avoided the problem.

Today it has started to crash again, with a very similar error, on displaying the functions hint.

[image: Picture of the IDE error, saying "Embarcadero RAD Studio for Windows not responding..."]

```
Firma problema:
  Nome evento problema: APPCRASH
  Nome applicazione:    bds.exe
  Versione applicazione:    21.0.17707.5020
  Timestamp applicazione:   545bd62a
  Nome modulo con errori:   jscript9.dll
  Versione modulo con errori:   11.0.9600.19375
  Timestamp modulo con errori:  5cde2a32
  Codice eccezione: c0000005
  Offset eccezione: 00091922
  Versione SO:  6.3.9600.2.0.0.272.33
  ID impostazioni locali:   1040
  Informazioni aggiuntive 1:    220c
  Ulteriori informazioni 2: 220c472d49ca3d9cceee350b34da06ab
  Ulteriori informazioni 3: debe
  Ulteriori informazioni 4: debe032f4e197ddaae37ab48b079ef65
```

Both errors also happen on a new project, created running the ide with the -r parameter:

```
bds.exe -r foo
```

Using *Process Monitor*, it seems that something is going wrong with internet explorer (?):

[image: Process Monitor's log]

Comment: Was a Windows Update applied recently?

Comment: I knew that Welcome Page is being basically displayed within a TWebBrowser component that is just a wrapper for Internet Explorer. But I never ever thought that Help insight is even remotely connected to Internet Explorer. If that is true then there will be lots of any Delphi users when Help systems stops working just because Microsoft decided to remove IE entirely.

Comment: @Olivier: No, the pc has not been updated for long time (And I'm suspecting that the problem is related to this, I will try to update the OS later)

Comment: @SilverWarior: I had some problems with the hints in past, using Delphi 2007, and I know that the hint is basically an HTML page (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51472972/delphi-2007-ide-hints-displayed-as-html-text))

Comment: @Olivier: Updating Windows completely resolved the problem. I also have enabled the welcome page again. Thanks for the hint

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to avoid the IDE crash, **but I'm still looking for a real solution**...

In `Tools` -> `Options` -> `Editor Options` -> `Code Insight`:

[image: Picture of the "tooltip help insight" option flag]

I've disabled the "Tooltip help insight" checkbox and the crash has been avoided (But obviously, I have no tooltip now....)